# PhusionPassenger::UnknownError when visiting canvas

Tags: ubuntu, ruby-on-rails

So I'm creating a canvas LMS server however I'm running into errors left and right. I recently got a forbidden error (which I was able to solve thanks to this great community). Now, server errors later I have another that I can't seem to solve. I'm getting an error from ruby rack:

```
Error message:
There was an error in your Gemfile, and Bundler cannot continue. (Bundler::GemfileError)

Exception class:
PhusionPassenger::UnknownError

Application root:
/var/canvas
```

List of gems:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (4.0.1)
actionpack (4.0.1)
activemodel (4.0.1)
activerecord (4.0.1)
activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
activesupport (4.0.1)
arel (4.0.1)
atomic (1.1.14)
builder (3.1.4)
bundler (1.3.5)
erubis (2.7.0)
hike (1.2.3)
i18n (0.6.5)
mail (2.5.4)
mime-types (1.25.1)
minitest (4.7.5)
multi_json (1.8.2)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.5.2)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (4.0.1)
railties (4.0.1)
rake (10.1.0)
sprockets (2.10.1)
sprockets-rails (2.0.1)
thor (0.18.1)
thread_safe (0.1.3)
tilt (1.4.1)
treetop (1.4.15)
tzinfo (0.3.38)
```

I've run updates on all my gems and nothing seems to have changed. I'm running ruby1.9.3 and the latest version (compatible with this version of ruby of course) of all the gems. None of the similar errors that I've found don't fix it. The GemFile is massive so I won't post it here but it's the default one after canvas is setup (if that helps at all). Gonna go keep trying to fix this.

I'm unfamilier with how the GemFile and ruby dependancies work. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

are you have swap memory?

generally PhusionPassenger generate these class of errors because the server does haven't swap memory, if you don't have swap memory I recommend that you configure a swap memory into server:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swap bs=1M count=1024
sudo mkswap /swap
sudo swapon /swap
```

I hope it works for you

Comment: Nope. Didn't work. D: